Can Windows 10 Search quickly find a file by filename (using wildcards)?
I know that Windows Search is smart at finding files by keywords inside the file. But now, can I search by the filename, not contents of the file? Such as  search  for  config.bin, to find the file such as my-config-2024.bin.  Of course, I can search from the command line: dir /s *config*.bin . But this takes time with a large drive and needs to be repeated for each drive.  Can the same be achieved quickly with Windows Search? I tried typing` *config*.bin in the search bar on the taskbar, but it only insists on Bing web search results. Can I  get files with this filename from my own PC, not web?

Windows Search supports "advanced queries" in the field:value syntax, so you should be able to search for:
file:config
 -or-
file:*config*.bin

More information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference (document is for 2.x but the current 3.x uses similar syntax)
an extensive list of windows search syntax

Alternatively, use the Everything indexer, which has an es command-line interface. (It uses the NTFS "USN Journal" to avoid the need for periodic reindexing, so it won't be as efficient if you have massive archives on FAT32/exFAT drives.)

Windows search was not made for quick and accurate searches:

As you noticed, if you type something in without specific lookups, Windows searches bunch of various places not even related to the files, such as Bing search engine. It gets more and more bloated with each new patch, too - e.g. with AI-related features.
By default it has only few places and limited set of extensions indexed, my-config-2024.bin may not be found at all if it's on a random drive. If you index your entire system, the search usually gets much slower, it's not too optimized.
You can disable indexing of the contents in Indexing options -> Advanced -> File types, but you can't disable anything else - the configurability barely exists. You can also use more specific file-only searches as the other answer mentions, but it's not too comfortable to use.

Everything has everything you need for extremely quick and accurate searches:

You can fully index all the drives in a matter of minutes, with much less CPU required. I'd recommend disabling Windows Indexer overall if you go for this solution, you could complement it with EverythingToolbar for similar accessibility.
To make it even faster, you can choose what to index in Tools -> Options... -> Indexes. E.g. if you often use sorting by last modified date, which is one of the most useful functionalities that helps with tracking file changes on the fly, you definitely want to index that.
By default it searches only names and finds them almost instantly even with few TB of data on all disks.

There's no reason to use Windows Search while this application exists.
